# Facing challenge populating html table using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here the below data is coming from database,

> Name     designatio salary  depart
>
> Vignesh  SE         50000   technical
>
> vivah    SSE        100000  technical

This I have to populate in html table using xslt as below table form.Here I should be able read column names as well.

> Name       vignesh     vivah
>
> Designation  SE            SSE
>
> salary       50000        100000
>
> depart         technical  technical

I tried like this by seeing some references,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title/>
            <style type="text/css">
                table.ma-temp-data-table {
                    margin:5px;
                }
                .ma-temp-data-table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
                        background-color:#eee;
                    }
                .ma-temp-data-table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
                        background-color:#ddd;
                    }
                .ma-temp-data-table th {
                        background-color:#ccc;
                    }
                .ma-temp-data-table td {
                    padding: 2px;
                }
                .ma-temp-data-table th {
                    padding: 4px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table class="ma-temp-data-table">
                <xsl:variable name="rowdata" select="root/row"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="$rowdata">
                <tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="$rowdata">

                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>

                        <td style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="$rowdata[$pos]"/></td>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The table is populating like this,

VigneshSE50000technical
vivahSSE100000technical

Here the problem is column space is not coming.
I'm new to XSLT ,can any one please help to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my solution for this,some have i'm able to find it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title/>
            <style type="text/css">
                table.ma-temp-data-table {
                    margin:5px;
                }
                .ma-temp-data-table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
                        background-color:#eee;
                    }
                .ma-temp-data-table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
                        background-color:#ddd;
                    }
                .ma-temp-data-table th {
                        background-color:#ccc;
                    }
                .ma-temp-data-table td {
                    padding: 2px;
                }
                .ma-temp-data-table th {
                    padding: 4px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table class="ma-temp-data-table">
                <xsl:variable name="rowdata" select="root/row"/>


                <tr>
                    <th>Field Name</th>
                    <th>Current Version</th>
                    <th>Previous Version</th>
                    <th>Original Version</th>

                </tr>

                <xsl:for-each select="$rowdata">


                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name() != 'event_type'][text()]">
                            <xsl:call-template name="output_row">
                                <xsl:with-param name="rowdata" select="$rowdata"/>  
                                <xsl:with-param name="fieldname" select="local-name()"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="fieldvalue" select="text()"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="output_row">
    <xsl:param name="rowdata"/>
    <xsl:param name="fieldname"/>
    <xsl:param name="fieldvalue"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldname"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldvalue"/>
        </td>

        <!--<td>
        <xsl:if test="$fieldname='status'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldname"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$fieldname!='status'">
            empty
        </xsl:if>
        </td>-->

        <xsl:for-each select="$rowdata">

            <xsl:if test="position()>1">
                <xsl:variable name="prevrowpos" select="position()-1"/>

                <td>
                    <!--<xsl:if test="./*[local-name()=$fieldname]/text() != $rowdata[$prevrowpos]/*[local-name()=$fieldname]/text() ">-->

                        <xsl:variable name="datavalue" select="./*[local-name()=$fieldname]/text()"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$datavalue"/>     
                    <!--</xsl:if>-->    
                </td>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```